Why does Danfojs fail to work with Vite React project
I'm trying to use Danfo.js with a React typescript project built using Vite.
I install it like so:
yarn add danfojs
Then I try the suggested start code:
import * as dfd from 'danfojs';

const dates : any = dfd.dateRange({
  start: '2017-01-01',
  end: '2020-01-01',
  period: 4,
  freq: 'Y'
});

const obj_data = {
  'A': dates,
  'B': ['bval1', 'bval2', 'bval3', 'bval4'],
  'C': [10, 20, 30, 40],
  'D': [1.2, 3.45, 60.1, 45],
  'E': ['test', 'train', 'test', 'train']
};

const df = new dfd.DataFrame(obj_data);
df.print();

However, I get the error:
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve entry for package "danfojs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
I've tried searching for why but I've only found one or two mentions of this issue online, and no working solutions.
Why is this occurring? How can I fix it?
